# Linked images in emails from my domain don't load in Apple Mail

Tags: html, image, email

I'm trying to put together some nice HTML emails that send when customers purchase from my online store (thanks for your order, your order has shipped, please review your order, etc.), rather than just relying on the ones that PayPal sends out, and I'm having trouble getting the images to display, specifically in Apple Mail. It isn't an issue with my client settings because I get images just fine from every other marketing email that hits my inbox.

I tried replacing one of my images with a random image from another website, just to see if it would load, and it did. So Apple Mail doesn't like my domain or images for some reason? There is also no link or button to opt to load them, they just show the broken image icon. Some show the alt text, some don't (which is another problem, I suppose).

I'm sending the email with PHP and not using any kind of marketing email service. Simply using an img tag with the linked URL to the images on my FTP server. For example:

`<img alt="Lynsey Schroeder Photography" src="https://lschroederphoto.com/img/lschroederphoto-logo.png" width="136"/>`

Is there a better way I should be doing this? It sounds like embedding the images with CID etc. is less compatible than just linking to them, but I could be wrong about that, this is new territory for me.

Or any other suggestions for what I might be doing wrong? Is my email not being considered trustworthy (I don't think that's the issue, because adding the sender address to my contacts and even VIPs doesn't solve the problem)?

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to look at sending images attached inline. Ultimately you have little control over how the email client will display your message. You might need the user to "trust" or otherwise interact with your messages before images will be displayed.

Comment: Can't really add much more without knowing what you're doing now. Use a commercial sender service perhaps?

Comment: Oh Wow. Have you opened https://lschroederphoto.com/img/lschroederphoto-logo.png? How large is that file? Ok, big dimensions but small size. That might be an issue. Also your IP was/is on uceprotectl3 blacklist which might contribute.

Comment: As I mentioned, the recipient "trusting" the sender doesn't help. Not using a commercial service, just sending with PHP. 

The logo is big dimension-wise, but same issue with small files like https://lschroederphoto.com/img/facebook-icon.png so that's also not the problem.

Comment: I have this problem as well with our email images, and my client is upset since he uses an iPhone. BlueHost says it's a problem with iOS, but their servers are fine. Our HTML email is coded like yours in the OP.

Comment: Apple Mail won't show images hosted by BlueHost for some reason. https://litmus.com/community/discussions/8954-images-load-in-every-email-client-but-apple-mail

Answer (score 0):

From my current experience: be sure apple mail does not just trick you with some caching.

I just made a html template, with images loading externally from our webserver. Apple Mail didn't display the image, just a placeholder question mark. I checked, and indeed the provided URL to the image was wrong in my template.

I fixed that so the path was truly correct, but Apple Mail never displayed that image anymore, it remembered in some cache that that image by this name was not reachable and didn't even try anymore to retrieve it.
I renamed the image file name and the path in my template, so it was a "new" image, and voila, Apple Mail found it and displays it since then.

(had the same effect with changed image content earlier ... new image, but apple mail kept displaying the old version from som cache, even for newly sent mails).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).